# C# Best way to check if any element in 2D array is NaN or Infinity

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Does anyone know what is the best way to check that none of the elements in a 2D array are NaN or Infinity? My array can be large so I would prefer not to loop through it. I am thinking of using

```
double[,] myArray;
if ( !double.IsNaN(myArray.Cast<double>().Min() ) && !double.IsInfinity( myArray.Cast<double>().Min() )
{
    // have finite values as elements
}
```

for the NaN and infinity check. I only need to know if there are any elements in the array that are NaN or infinity so I figure just checking the smallest element in the array should do the trick for the NaN and for infinity. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you for any help or suggestions you may be able to provide.

Comment: I would suggest storing `myArray.Cast<double>().Min()` in a variable to avoid calculating it twice.

Comment: @mayabelle Thank you. I was made aware of it but have not reedited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A hand coded loop is much faster than the suggested Linq alternative.  See UPDATE 2 below.*

One way or another, you are going to loop through every element of the array to answer your question since there is no ordering specified for the array.

Your code does just that, hiding the implementation of the loop.  Doing the loop with Linq is will be at least marginally slower than writing your own `for` loop, since it does more work.  (In fact, you loop through the array twice at the moment since you do not cache the result of `myArray.Cast<double>().Min()`).

For most processors you should traverse the loop in [row major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), as it traverses adjacent memory addresses (in my own tests, it can be 30% slower to traverse in the wrong order).

If there is in fact some order to the values in the array, a more efficient search may be possible.

**UPDATE**

I suspect that a hand-coded loop will be significantly faster than using Linq since the loop body is trivial.  If every last bit of performance is important, I suggest you implement both options and benchmark.

Reed's suggestion to run in parallel is worth benchmarking as well.  You can parallelize a traditional iteration very easily using [Parallel.For](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**UPDATE 2**

Measured the performance of Reed's solution and a hand-coded loop.

Linq: 1448.6353 ms

For loop: 125.2208 ms

Code used:

```
class Program
{
    const int SIZE = 3000;
    static double[,] data = new double[SIZE,SIZE];


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length >= 1 && args[0] == "/for")
        {
            Benchmark(ForLoop);
        }
        else
        {
            Benchmark(LinqLoop);
        }
    }

    static void ForLoop()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if (double.IsNaN(data[i, j]) || double.IsInfinity(data[i, j])) Console.WriteLine("FOUND!");
            }
        }
    }

    static void LinqLoop()
    {
        if (!data.Cast<double>().Any(d => double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d))) Console.WriteLine("FOUND!");
    }

    static void Benchmark(Action a)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        a();

        TimeSpan span = watch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("Milliseconds: " + span.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand about the looping. I meant to say writing an explicit set of nested for loops. Will my code do the trick? Will it catch positive infinity as well? Also, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @PBrenek I don't believe it will catch positive infinity, the way you wrote it... It's also far less efficient than it could be.

Comment: @Eric J Thank you. I realize the double looping in the code posted. I did not know about iterating in row major order first. Finally, there is no a priori ordering of the values in the array. I am lookin gfor the fastest way to do this check.

Comment: @Eric J I was not aware of Parallel.For. I guess I will need to benchmark both approaches. Thank you.

Comment: @EricJ - Your code isn't the same - You're using if `(!data.Cast` with LINQ, but using `if (true` in the loop... (Doesn't impact the timings, though - it's still far slower)

Comment: Wow. I wouldn't have expected that magnitude of a difference in performance. I ran a similar test with a 5000x5000 array of doubles (25,000,000 elements). Release build targeting x86, I got the following best of 10 for each: Linq: 4.7737837 seconds, Iteration: 0.1292544 seconds, pointer arithmetic: 0.1297875 seconds.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: If there were any NaN or Infinity in the test data, Linq would terminate earlier.  The nested `for` should actually do something like `return true;` if the condition is met to match the OP's actual requirement.  I was interested in just scanning a the same array with both approaches to test the Linq overhead when the loop body is trivial.

Comment: @NicholasCarey: The iteration and pointer arithmetic cases are too close to call given the timer resolution.  It would be interesting to see a run with more elements to see if there is any significant difference.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally use:

```
if (!myArray.Cast<double>().Any(d => double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d)))
{
     // All have correct values...
```

In addition to being shorter, this should approach the speed of a manually written loop, as it keeps it to a single pass through the values, and exits immediately if a "bad" value is reached (since `Any()` will stop evaluating on a failure).

---

> Since my array can get large, I guess I will write loops to get the better performance/

One option, if you're dealing with very large arrays, would be to do this check in parallel:

```
if (!myArray.Cast<double>().AsParallel()
            .Any(d => double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d)))
{
     // All have correct values...
```

With a very large array, this will typically out perform a direct loop, as multiple cores can handle the partitioned data via PLINQ.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of Any(). I would actually prefer not to use Linq but then I guess I am back to writing my own loop.

Comment: @PBrenek Yes- if you want to avoid LINQ, then you could write a loop.  That's actually likely going to be (very slightly) faster, but this will be the next best option...

Comment: @PBrenek Note that you're already using LINQ (with the `Cast<T>` "trick"), so using `Any()` seems like a natural extension of that...

Comment: I realize that I was using Linq. I assumed that this approach might be slightly better performance wise than writing loops. Since my array can get large, I guess I will write loops to get the better performance/

Comment: @PBrenek I personally wouldn't bother unless you find a *measured* performance problem.  The difference in speed with looping is going to be very minor.  You could also potentially parallelize this, which could give some benefits...

Comment: I was not aware that this was even possible. Thank you for informing me of this. It is very good to know. However, performance is an issue as this is part of real time signal processing code so every bit of performance I can extract from every step the better it is.

Comment: Note that parallel Linq is only (potentially) faster if there is more than one core available.  When I think signal processing, I think of the possibility this could be an embedded system with potentially less capable processors than a desktop or server class machine.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: If the body of the loop is a test for IsNaN and IsInfinity, are you sure LINQ's overhead is only trivial?  Seems it could actually be significant for such a trivial loop body.

Comment: @Eric J Thank you. You are correct but this is run from a desktop machine with parallel cores.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I ended up benchmarking the alternatives and a nested `for` loop is more than 10x faster than Linq in my specific test.  Details posted in my answer.

Comment: @Eric J. Wow. That was very interesting. Thank you. Would you happen to have a feel how doing this via unsafe code (pointers) would compare performance wise?

Answer (score 1):

> "My array can be large so I would prefer not to loop through it."

Looping through it is the only way to access all elements. A loop is required one way or another.

If you're concerned about performance you should not use LINQ as it will incur iterator and delegate call overhead. Use `unsafe` code to run through all elements of that array by treating it as a 1D array.

The JIT cannot optimize away bounds checks for multi-dimensional arrays.

Like this:

```
fixed (double* arrayPtr = array) {
 var count = width * height;
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  if (double.IsNaN(arrayPtr[i]) || double.IsInfinity(arrayPtr[i]))
   return true;
 }
}
return false;
```

Probably 10x faster than the LINQ solution. LINQ is very indirection-heavy which is poison for performance on modern CPUs. Straight-line loop-based code is usually significantly faster.

Comment: Yes, because it gets rid of the bounds checks and index calculations.

Comment: Any suggestions on how best to implement this? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is certainly the fastest option. Am I even addressing your question? I took the question as a performance question.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution does two passes over your array. You could do this (Linqy):

```
static bool HasBadData( double[,] doubles )
{
  bool hasBadData = doubles.Cast<double>()
                           .Any( x => double.IsInfinity(x) || double.IsNaN(x) )
                           ;
  return hasBadData ;
}
```

Or the more straightforward, non-Linq way:

```
static bool HasBadData( double[,] doubles )
{
  bool hasBadData = false ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; !hasBadData && i < doubles.GetLength(0) ; ++i )
  {
    for ( int j = 0 ; !hasBadData && j < doubles.GetLength( 1 ) ; ++j )
    {
      double d = doubles[i,j] ;
      hasBadData = double.IsInfinity(d) || double.IsNaN(d) ;
    }
  }
  return hasBadData ;
}
```

It's six of one and half a dozen of the other, really, though I suspect the non-Linq approach will perform marginally better.